# datagridview multiplying cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem with `DataGridView`. I want to multiply two cells and display the result in a third cell.

I have two `DataGridView`s. The first `DataGridView` gets data from database. The second `DataGridView` gets values after I select row from first `DataGridView` and adds that row to second `DataGridView`. Column A gets from first `DataGridView` (from database); in column B the user inserts values manually.

```
example of second datagridview: 
Price |  Amount  |  Total
10.50 | 2        | 21.00
5.20  | 4        | 20.80
7.30  | 5        | 36.50
```

After that I want to sum column C and display the sum in a text box.

Column A is type decimal; Column B is integer; Column C should be decimal too.

This is solution that one guy gave me on internet but it works only for `DataGridView` that gets data manually, it doesn't work if data is from database:

```
decimal sum = 0.0m;

for (int i = 0; i < gridProizvodi.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = gridProizvodi.Rows[i];
    if (row.IsNewRow) break;
    decimal product = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Value)
                    * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);

    sum += product;
    row.Cells[3].Value = product;
}

txtCijena.Text= sum.ToString();
```

I get an `argument out of range exception was unhandled` error in this line

```
decimal product = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Value)
                * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
```

Can someone help me find a solution?

Comment: I'd start by setting a breakpoint on that line.  What's the value of `row.Cells.length`?  Is `[1]` a valid index?  What's the value of `row.Cells[1].Value` and `row.Cells[2].Value`?  Can they be parsed?  Perhaps you're walking over a header or footer row with no cells?

Comment: Row.Cells[1] i decimal number, Row.Cells[2] in integer, Row.Cells[3] would be value Cell1 * value Cell 3 (decimal number * integer).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yw8ixgcses5sf31/databridview.png
image of form

Comment: try rows.Cells[3].value = product.ToString(). Also, I recommend you to use instead of the cells index, the column name. Then, if you add columns, you dont have to reorder all the indexes in your code.

Comment: try rows.Cells[3].value = product.ToString(). does't work.

Comment: try this `decimal product = decimal.Parse(row.Cells[1].EdittedFormattedValue.ToString())
                * int.Parse(row.Cells[2].EdittedFormattedValue.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using forms or webapp... The folloing option is ususally aplicable to webapps, I don't know about forms.

This usually happens when the GridView columns are generated automatically, i.e. `gridview.AutoGenerateColumns = true;`. It does not know that there are any columns, therefore gives you an`out of range` exception. You would need to set it to false and tell it what columns to display. In the template field for the third column, you can simply change the binding property to a multiplicated value.

Another oprion would be to return three columns from the database, third column being your multiplied values.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm using Form. gridview.AutoGenerateColumns = true; i have put this on false. I'll try what you wrote and see if it works.

ty

Answer (score 0):

if error happened on the line as you sad. Then faster solution will be to use a column names.
As @Andres mentioned it is better practice then using of indexes.

From form designer check a columns name and then use like this:

```
decimal product = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[datagridviewTextBoxColumn1.Name].Value)
                * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[datagridviewTextBoxColumn2.Name].Value);
```

Or much better will be to used custom names of columns.

Have your second datargidview a predefined columns or it created programmatically?

if they have a predefined names-> then use them

if they not -> then, because you have always same columns in second datagridview, then will be better to create columns once in designer for example

Comment: I have predefined columns in second gdv. I have tryed with column names instead of indexes, but id doesn't work

Comment: @LukaRoguljic, did you used a names of predefined columns? And how you add rows to second dgv?

Answer (score 0):

How if you change it like this

```
decimal sum = 0.0m;
decimal product = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < gridProizvodi.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = gridProizvodi.Rows[i];
    if (row.IsNewRow) break;
    product = row.item("Price") * row.item("Amount");
    '--- if your price and amount field is numeric type, you dont have to convert it

    sum += product;
    row.item("Total") = product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in VB.NET then......

```
Dim sum As Decimal = 0D

For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(i)
    If row.IsNewRow Then
        Exit For
    End If

    Dim product As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells("Column1").Value) * _
            Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells("Column2").Value)
    'sum += product
    row.Cells("Column3").Value = product
Next
```

Thank You!!

Comment: tried to format your code (not overly successful ;-) - please edit and improve